# Xamarin Forms custom keyboard Unicode characters

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to build a custom Keyboard in Xamarin Forms application that uses Unicode symbols instead of standard ASCII layout but these symbols are not displayed in standard Editor or Entry components whenever I press the respective buttons on the keyboard.

My implementation is completely based on [this](https://github.com/FabriBertani/CustomKeyboardXamarinForms?source=post_page-----4fa3b83dad1d----------------------) Github repo. If I change the original layout XML file from this repository to include even one of the Unicode characters that I am aiming for, that particular button won't print the symbol:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="8%p"
    android:keyHeight="50dp"
    android:horizontalGap="1%p"
    android:verticalGap="1%p">

    <Row android:keyHeight="4dp" android:rowEdgeFlags="top" android:verticalGap="1%p">
        <Key android:codes="0" android:keyWidth="100%p" android:keyIcon="@drawable/kb_separator_line" />
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="0" android:keyWidth="0dp" android:horizontalGap="2%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="0x10D0" android:keyLabel="ა" android:keyWidth="18%p" />   
        <Key android:codes="30" android:keyLabel="B" android:keyWidth="18%p" />
        <Key android:codes="31" android:keyLabel="C" android:keyWidth="18%p" />
        <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="D" android:keyWidth="18%p" />
        <Key android:codes="33" android:keyLabel="E" android:keyWidth="18%p" />
        <Key android:codes="0" android:keyWidth="0dp" android:horizontalGap="2%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"  />
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="0" android:keyWidth="0dp" android:horizontalGap="2%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="8" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyWidth="18%p" />
        <Key android:codes="9" android:keyLabel="2" android:keyWidth="18%p" />
        <Key android:codes="10" android:keyLabel="3" android:keyWidth="18%p" />
        <Key android:codes="11" android:keyLabel="4" android:keyWidth="18%p" />
        <Key android:codes="12" android:keyLabel="5" android:keyWidth="18%p" />
        <Key android:codes="0" android:keyWidth="0dp" android:horizontalGap="2%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"  />
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="0" android:keyWidth="0dp" android:horizontalGap="2%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="13" android:keyLabel="6" android:keyWidth="18%p" />
        <Key android:codes="14" android:keyLabel="7" android:keyWidth="18%p" />
        <Key android:codes="15" android:keyLabel="8" android:keyWidth="18%p" />
        <Key android:codes="16" android:keyLabel="9" android:keyWidth="18%p" />
        <Key android:codes="7" android:keyLabel="0" android:keyWidth="18%p" />
        <Key android:codes="0" android:keyWidth="0dp" android:horizontalGap="2%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"  />
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="0" android:keyWidth="0dp" android:horizontalGap="2%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="67" android:keyLabel="DELETE" android:keyWidth="37%p" />
        <Key android:codes="66" android:keyLabel="ENTER" android:keyWidth="56%p" />
        <Key android:codes="0" android:keyWidth="0dp" android:horizontalGap="2%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"  />
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

Notice the  `<Key android:codes="0x10D0" android:keyLabel="ა" android:keyWidth="18%p" />`   line where a letter 'ა' from Georgian alphabet is present with its Unicode value in hex. I have tried decimal values for android:codes, as well as using '\u' format for android:keyLabel, but no matter what I do, the symbol is not displayed when running this application on Android.

If I programmatically insert this or any other Georgian symbol into Editor or Entry it gets displayed, so I know my problem is not related to my particular Android version or Tablet not having support for these symbols.

I am using Lenovo TB-X304L with Android 6.1. What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a solution for this specific issue so instead I decided to supply negative index values for `android:codes` and then check for these values in the overriden `OnKey()` method and manually append the respective characters to the Entry/Editor.